# Symbolic Link Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, cmd.exe, symbolic-link

My 120 GB SSD is currently at about max capacity and I mistakenly installed too many programs on that drive including Visual Studio and IntelliJ and Eclipse, which take up a lot of space. I wan't to move all of these programs into my 1TB Hard Drive to free up space and I'm not seeing very good explanations on how to do this anywhere. Is there any issues with creating a symbolic link to do this, such as:

```
mklink /d "C:\Program Files (x86)" "D:\SymlinkC"
```

Also, does the folder I want to save space on need to be first in the syntax like above?

Also just wondering if the easiest thing to do is simply reinstall all of the programs or if there is a better/easier way to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: Just uninstall the programs and install them on your other drive.  "Is there any issues with creating a symbolic link to do this" - Yes

Comment: If you only make the symbolic link of program files the program data and user local data will remain in that SSD.

Answer (score 1):

Some report it will work, but this is still a HUGE change to a VERY important part of Windows, and not one that is officially supported in any way.

The better idea would be to find those parts of the applications that are taking the most space and migrate those. Or move specific applications using Symlinks rather than the entire Program Files.

The benefits of this will be that in the case something goes wrong you're only missing that application and not the entire Program Files directory.